# React: Convert firebase url to file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

SO basically I am able to save file uploaded from my photo folder to firebase storage in the back end. The quest is how do I do the reverse by getting the firebase link and converting it back to a file type.
Note that I tried to use fetch but I got a cors error
so from

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/high420canna.appspot.com/o/2-1-licence.jpg?generation=1599252825564179&alt=media
```

to

```
File
​
    lastModified: 1596050200610
​
    name: "2-1-licence.jpg"
​
    size: 1209846
​
    type: "image/jpeg"
​
webkitRelativePath: "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the download URL for a file by calling the `getDownloadURL()` method on a storage reference.

```js
storageRef.child('images/image.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/image.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();

  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

Have a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) official documentation from Firebase for more details.

Comment: isnt that just the url link though as opposed to a file object?